# how can i make this ajax code work with any kind of html file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a *ajax* call which will get some data from database and I have to load these into a html file. But, the problem is I have different html files and I do not know the content of html file

I have tried it for around 2-3 days and have searched different ways to append data to a html file.
I have made some changes in the code. please assume that the code is working fine.
thank you.

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  "api/dataFromDataBase",
            success: function (data) {
                tableHead = data[0].split("?");//contains data from database
                $("#databaseContent").append("<tr>");
                for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
                    $("#databaseContent").append("<th>" + tableHead[i] + "</th>");
                }
                $("#tableHeading").append("</tr>");
                tableHead += data[0]; 
                $("#FromHtml").append(data[1]);
            },   
        });
```

in this file `#databaseContent` is an *id* in the html, so i can easily append the data. but I have no idea about what the html contains. Is their any way i can append data to it??

Comment: You could traverse through tags or classes.. like find table tag in body instead of id?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a point of injection on a successful Ajax call. You can append this entire table at the end of the html page.

```
// all of this within the success call of the AJAX
var tableHead = data[0].split("?");//contains data from database
var tableEle = document.createElement("table");
var tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

var tableTr = document.createElement("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
  var cell = document.createElement("th");
  var cellText = document.createTextNode(tableHead[i]);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
}
tableBody.appendChild(tableTr);
tableEle.appendChild(tableBody);
document.body.appendChild(tableEle);
```

What we are trying to do here is, create a table element and within the loop creating the content of the table and at the end we're appending the newly created table to the 
"document.body". This should work for all html since all html pages have a body tag.

Comment: firstly, thanks for your hard work. I had done this thing ,but i don't want table to append at the end of the file. I want it to append it into a tag inside a html file. whose id is unknown to me!!!
if i can find the id some how then i can append . but that is the major problem i have

Comment: @lunaticprince - well, what information do you have available to you, that you can't make sense of? Without some form of policy, rules or direction it seems ludacrous to think that anyone here has a hope in hell of knowing the right answer. Sure, someone will guess okay - but why should they have to? Why is not the information needed to make the decision present in the question? If it doesn't exist, how do you imagine we can help?

Comment: well, this is what i was said to do and i was and even now trying to solve this problem. Even i think that it is near to impossible, but if their is someone who can get solution for this problem then it will help me and may be others.I tried my best to find a way to get the answer, and at last i had no choice other than asking here!

Comment: @lunaticprince do you know what tag it is where you want to insert? otherwise, it is (like you said) near to impossible. And not knowing where you would be inserting sounds dodgy tbh.